# Handle terminated state using flutter local notifications & FCM

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, flutter-local-notification

I'm created a handler for incoming FCM using flutter local notifications & on tap on each notification it can navigate to a specific screen and that working properly as soon as the app in the foreground and background but when the app terminated it navigates me to the home screen instead.

I use FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage() as a listener in case of background & terminated & FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen() in case of background with flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show() in both cases

Answer (score 1):

When app is closed, you need to check for the notification that was clicked when the app was opened.

use:

```
  final RemoteMessage? initialMessage =
        await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage();
```

to get the initial message somewhere while initializing your app and handle it if it is not null

Sometimes you might have to add a short delay to handle it after the rest of your app has been initialized. You can use

```
Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 300)).then((value){
 // handle it in here
)};
```

Don't forget to do this after you call

```
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
```

Comment: That exactly what I need but I need this to detect "flutter local notification" tab instead of default FCM, is that possible?

Comment: Oh I see that in your question now. Since the other firebase listeners work with local notification does this not? I searched for it and don't know. If it does not I will delete my answer so someone else might help you